# Backing up an External USB Drive to TimeMachine then Restoring Without Drive Connected?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, restore

I have just configured my iMac to backup my external USB harddrive in addition to the internal drive.

I have just tested restoring some files from the TimeMachine backup, by selecting the USB drive down the LHS under TimeMachine, selecting the file I want to restore and that all works fine.

However, I'm wondering, what if my external drive one day dies - It won't show down the LHS as a device under Time Machine (I simulated this by simply disconnecting the usb drive a moment ago) - How do I then point to the files that I need to restore?

I'm sure there must be a simple answer to this, but am a newbie to TimeMachine.